# Remove the white colour around the number (percentage) in pie options Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I need one help on high chart options,

How to remove the white colour around the percentage with in the pie chart options.
I have attached the image, please see that and help me for this issue.
 [Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6cHv.png)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by modifying the [`textOutline`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.style.textOutline) style property like:

```
...
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            datalabels: {
                style: {
                    textOutline: false
              }
            }
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: Thanks wergeld , really i didn't expect this much fastest response.
Thank you very much...